# Understanding conclusion from: $-\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I see that if it holds that

$$\newcommand{\dx}{\,\mathrm{d}x}
-\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|\dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|\dx
$$

We can conclude that:

$$
\Big|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\dx\Big| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)| \dx
$$

And i dont see how they concluded that.

Thank you.

Comment: If $-b\le a\le b$, then surely $|a|\le b$, no?

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: By the way the conclusion is a special case of the Jensen inequality

Answer (score 0):

Since $-|f|\leq f\leq |f|$, then $$-\int|f|\leq \int f\leq \int|f|,$$
holds. Moreover, if $a\leq b\leq c$, then $$|b|\leq \max\{|a|,|c|\}.$$

apply this to $$b=\int f,\quad  a=-\int|f|\quad \text{and}\quad c=\int|f|,$$ the claim follow.

Comment: Thank you also for the help